# How to properly do paging and manage memory gracefully in windows 8 HTML app?

Tags: windows-8

I have a requirement that I think is common in many applications: paging. I have chosen to go with the "press to load 10 more" pattern, I think it looks better in a Metro app instead of using page numbers.

The problem I am facing is memory related. I load the first 10 items, which contain some images, and as I press "load more", I notice that the memory of the application is increased proportionally, obviously because of the images loaded. It soon gets to the 150MB memory limit where the operating system might actually kill the app.

What I am thinking is if there was some way after you scroll to the next page for the images not visible anymore to be unloaded from memory. This is gracefully handled by the iOS with the GetCell method, but is there an equivalent pattern in Windows 8 Javascript model?

Thanks,
Themos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metro style apps usually do infinite scrolling using data virtualization.  Check out the [Build](http://www.buildwindows.com/) sessions on Data Virtualization in Metro style apps:

- [Build polished collection and list apps using XAML](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-517T)
- [Build data-driven collection and list apps using XAML](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-912T)
- [Build polished collection and list apps in HTML5](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-209T)
- [Build data-driven collection and list apps using ListView in HTML5](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/APP-210T)

For example: [HTML ListView working with data sources sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-custom-data-4dcfb128)

Comment: So does data virtualization solve the memory problem for items not in view?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use the sample you posted because Microsoft does no longer issue ApplicationIds. Is there any other way I can try this?